# Why my Ajax code is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I am trying to send and receive a data through ajax. But It doesn't work. I don't know what I did mistake on my code.

Here is my code:

> I tried the below code

**Jquery AJAX code**

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'AjaxSecurity.aspx?securityLevelOrUser=SecurityLevel&SecurityKey=1&ReportName=TotalSales',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: 'json',
            dataType: 'json',   //If I remove this line it's call AjaxSucceeded but result is undefined
            cache: false,
            success: AjaxSucceeded,
            error: AjaxFailed
        });
        function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
            alert("hello");
            alert(result.d);
        }
        function AjaxFailed(result) {
            alert("Error");
            alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
        }
```

> it alert1= `Error` and alert2= `200 ok`

**Server Side code**

```
public class GetResult
{
    public string removedReportName { get; set; }
    public string removedColumnNames { get; set; }
    public string removedFilterNames { get; set; }
}

public partial class AjaxSecurity : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        string securityLevelOrUser = Request["securityLevelOrUser"].ToString();

        if (securityLevelOrUser.Equals("SecurityLevel"))
        {
            string jsonString = js.Serialize(getResultBySecurityLevel(Request["SecurityKey"], Request["ReportName"]));
            Response.Write(jsonString);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    private GetResult getResultBySecurityLevel(string securityLevel,string reportName)
    {
        GetResult getResult = new GetResult();

        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HQWebMatajer13"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ReportHide,RColumnName,RFilterName FROM SecurityLevelDetails WHERE SecurityLevel=@SecurityLevel and ReportName=@ReportName";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportName", reportName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecurityLevel", securityLevel);

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rd=cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while(rd.Read())
            {
                getResult.removedReportName = rd["ReportHide"].ToString();
                getResult.removedColumnNames = rd["RColumnName"].ToString();
                getResult.removedFilterNames = rd["RFilterName"].ToString();
            }

        }

        return getResult;
    }

}
```

And I have one more doubt. 
When I google regarding Ajax using asp.net, Some of them using **webservice,webmethod,server side code**.

> where we can implement webmethod?. In which scenario basis we can use web Method?
>
> **Updated**
>
> Previous Errors are fixed
>
> dataType: 'json',   //If I remove this line it's call AjaxSucceeded but result is undefined

Comment: Have you tested your server-side code other than through the `$.get()` call?

Comment: @nnnnnn Can you check my update now?.

Comment: I don't understand what behaviour you are trying to describe. You say you did get a server error, but then you say you fixed that, so why even mention it? Please [edit] your question to clearly explain the *current* behaviour, and the desired behaviour.

Comment: Any console errors? "It doesn't work" is not a great description